# NancyFx binding a model to a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, .net, model-binding, nancy

In Nancy, is there a way to bind the content of a POST request to a dynamic type?

For example:.

```
// sample POST data: { "Name": "TestName", "Value": "TestValue" }

// model class
public class MyClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// NancyFx POST url
Post["/apiurl"] = p => {

    // this binding works just fine
    var stronglyTypedModel = this.Bind<MyClass>();

    // the following bindings do not work
    // there are no 'Name' or 'Value' properties on the resulting object
    dynamic dynamicModel1 = this.Bind();
    var dynamicModel2 = this.Bind<dynamic>();
    ExpandoObject dynamicModel3 = this.Bind();
    var dynamicModel4 = this.Bind<ExpandoObject>();

}
```

Comment: Can't you just do Post["/apiurl"] = p => { dynamic model = p; string name = model.Name; string val = model.Value; }?

Comment: @Alexander, pls post u'r comment as an answer to get the rep when it's due :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexander. 'p' is already a dynamic type, but I can't access the data in the request body because it needs to be deserialized first. If it were a query string or route parameter, I could access it from 'p', but in this case I need to deserialize JSON data from the request body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Out of the box Nancy does not support dynamic model binding. TheCodeJunkie has written a quick ModelBinder to achieve that tho.

https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/5521941

Then you can use it like so

`dynamic model = this.Bind<DynamicDictionary>();`

Comment: Thanks guys. I copied and modified the default model binder to suit my needs, but the binder by CodeJunkie is much cleaner. :)

Comment: @user326502: can you share your solution to make his modelbinder work with POST actions?

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers point, there is no support for binding directly to a dynamic type, the most similar one is the ModelBinder provided by TheCodeJunkie in https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/5521941

However, this approach has a problem, and is that the DynamicDictionary resulting from this code does not serialize later properly, producing only the keys of the dictionary and losing the values. This is described here [Why does storing a Nancy.DynamicDictionary in RavenDB only save the property-names and not the property-values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178704/why-does-storing-a-nancy-dynamicdictionary-in-ravendb-only-save-the-property-nam) and as of today (version 1.4.3) is still happening, limiting seriously this approach.

The solution is to use a simple trick, accessing the raw data received in the POST and deserializing using JSON.Net. In your example it would be:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Extensions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Post["/apiurl"] = p => {
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(Request.Body.AsString());

    //Now you can access the object using its properties
    return Response.AsJson((object)new { a = obj.Prop1 });
}
```

Note that you need to use Nancy.Extensions for the Request.Body.AsString() call.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to deserialize my POST body as dynamic and found this question, I’ll put my solution using Newtonsoft and extension method just in case that result useful for somebody else.

**Extension method**

```
using System.IO;
using Nancy;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace NancyFx
{
    public static class DynamicModelBinder
    {
        public static dynamic ToDynamic(this NancyContext context)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using Nancy;
using Nancy.ModelBinding;

namespace NancyFx
{
    public class HomeModule : NancyModule
    {
        public HomeModule(IAppConfiguration appConfig)
        {
            Post("/product", args => {
                dynamic product = Context.ToDynamic();
                string name = product.Name;
                decimal price = product.Price;
                return Response.AsJson(new {IsValid=true, Message= "Product added sucessfully", Data = new {name, price} });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but you can try:

```
dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
model = Request; //or Request.Form
return View["ViewName", model];
```

let me know if works :)